# Calling JavaScript function in a .js file from ApiController

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm trying to call a JavaScript function from an ApiController. I don't know if it's possible because since it's API the page which has the Js code won't be loaded. I need to read it from the file and make it work somehow I think.

The js part which I'm trying to call, this is inide a .js file called editDetail.js

```
var fn = Function("item", validateString);
    var validateresult = fn(obj);
    return validateresult;
```

I'm not really sure if it's possible to make this work. If it is ,how?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to be able to do this but all I can tell you is that what you are asking is not possible. The API controller has no access to the scripts. You could use the .success method of an ajax call (which called the API controller) to call the method you need.
EDIT:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'yourcontroller/youraction',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
              //call the other .js method here
             }    
        });
```

Comment: We have some UI based operations and some web service based one working on same kind of records. I just needed to add some functionality of UI based flow to web api flow

Comment: I updated my answer, I think ajax call is the way to go for your problem

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I'm not trying to call C# from Js. I'm trying to call Js from C#. I think we'll end up trying something entirely different on this problem.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do? So the API is not called by the page? Then why must it reach a javascript function (which works in a page). Ajax makes the call to your API and when the API call is done, it can execute the javascript function. If this is not what you are looking for, then can you please update your question to help myself and other users understand your problem?